# MySQL - Optimise GROUP BY Query with un-indexed fields in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, query-optimization

I am currently trying to improve the performance of the following `GROUP BY` query on the INSPECTION table in my database.

```
SET @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE = 'B1010-V001';

SELECT  EQUIPMENT_ID
        , CML_ID
        , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'S' THEN 'S' END)                                             AS SCOPED_INSPECTIONS
        , MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS IN('A','R') THEN INSPECTION_DATE END)                                    AS MAX_INSPECTION_DATE
        , MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS IN('A','R') THEN CORROSION_RATE_ACTUAL_SHORT_TERM_MM_PER_YEAR END)       AS MAX_CORROSION_RATE_ACTUAL_SHORT_TERM_MM_PER_YEAR
FROM INSPECTION
WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE
GROUP BY EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID;
```

The query currently has an execution time of 0.094 sec. I have noticed that by removing the three un-indexed aggregate statements in my `SELECT` query that the execution time is reduced to 0.000 sec. So my question is... Is there a way to either re-design my current `GROUP BY` query, or optimize my aggregate statements in some way to improve the query time? I have provided the DDL and size of the INSPECTION table below...

**Record Count:** 218,000

DDL / Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.INSPECTION
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                  /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `INSPECTION_NO`                                 INT NOT NULL,
    `STATUS`                                        enum('P','A','S','R') NOT NULL default 'P',
    `CML_ID`                                        INT NOT NULL,
    `EQUIPMENT_ID`                                  VARCHAR(20),
    `INSPECTION_TYPE`                               VARCHAR(50),
    `SCOPE_COMMENTS`                                TEXT,
    `NOMINAL_WALL_THICKNESS`                        DOUBLE,
    `MINIMUM_REMAINING_WALL_THICKNESS`              DOUBLE,
    `WALL_LOSS`                                     DOUBLE,
    `SERVICE_YEARS`                                 DOUBLE,
    `CORROSION_RATE_ACTUAL_SHORT_TERM_MM_PER_YEAR`  DOUBLE,
    `CONDITION`                                     VARCHAR(50),
    `INSPECTION_DATE`                               DATE,
    `NDT_REPORT_NUMBER`                             VARCHAR(20),
    `INSPECTION_COMMENTS`                           TEXT,
    `INSPECTION_SCOPE`                              TEXT,
    `WORK_ORDER`                                    TEXT,
    `INPECTOR_NAME`                                 VARCHAR(50),
    `INPECTION_COMPANY`                             VARCHAR(50),
    `PHOTO`                                         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID, INSPECTION_NO),
    FOREIGN KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID) REFERENCES CML(EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID),

    /*ADD TABLE INDEXES TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE*/
    /*INDEX ON PHOTO FIELD REQUIRED TO ALLOW AUTO INCREMENTING OF FIELD*/
    INDEX `PHOTO` (`PHOTO`)
    -- INDEX INSPECTION_DATE (INSPECTION_DATE)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Results from an EXPLAIN query are provided below...

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------+------------+----------+-------+--------+-----------+--------------+
| id |  select_type |    table    |  partitions |  type  |    possible_keys    |     key    |  key_len |  ref  |  rows  |  filtered |     Extra    |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------+------------+----------+-------+--------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 |  SIMPLE      |  INSPECTION |  NULL       |  index |  'PRIMARY', 'PHOTO' |  'PRIMARY' |       30 |  NULL | 218851 |       100 |  Using where |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------+------------+----------+-------+--------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Which columns currently have an index?

Comment: EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID, INSPECTION_NO is the primary key index as per schema provided above

Comment: Can you run `EXPLAIN` on your query?

Comment: @Tim see updated answer

Comment: You don't have an index on `STATUS`, so I see no way that the third to fifth terms in the `SELECT` clause could possibly avoid a full table scan.

Comment: @Tim I added a index to the status field as suggested and this made little to no difference in the query time.

Comment: It may not be possible to significantly speed up your query then.  Conditional aggregation has some overhead to it.  Perhaps you can rephrase your query somehow?

Comment: Did you get any warnings?  Was `@EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE` a string or was it a number?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Not a full table scan, but a range scan of all rows `WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE`.

Comment: @Rick James - See updated question, now includes an example parameter. It is a var char.

Comment: @Tim - Any ideas on how the query can be rephrased to achieve the same result?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, though 0.1 sec for 200K records using aggregation doesn't sound particularly bad to me.  Are you planning on running this query on a massive scale/very often?

Comment: Yes this is planned to be used as part of a AFTER UPDATE trigger to keep calculations refreshed database. So I don't really want the 0.1 second overhead each time someone issues an update statement to the database. Additionally I am generally curious as to how these types of queries can be optimized for future reference.

Comment: Ouch!  Don't scan anything inside a Trigger.  If you can see from the update whether a number should change by 1, then use that.

Comment: If you are in a Trigger, you don't start with any @variables.  Use `NEW.xxx` or whatever you have there.

Comment: How do you expect to shovel that `SELECT` into "refreshing calculations"?

Comment: Ok, so this query is not directly inside a trigger, it is only a small sample of a much larger update statement in a stored procedure which is then called by an after UPDATE trigger. But I think this is irrelevant my specific question is asking how to optimize the sample query not how this query integrates with the rest of my overall system.